# Jsoup paring in listview

Tags: android, jsoup

I have a problem with parsing a wiki page using Jsoup in a listview:

```
try {
    // NB: controllate di importare le classi giuste
    // all'inizio ci deve essere org.jsoup

    // ricavo l'html della pagina con user agent desktop (Chrome)
    // e timeout 30000
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://it.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sonno")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22")
            .timeout(30000).get();

    // prendo la tabella
    // (con .first() ottengo il primo elemento, in questo caso l'unico )
    Element tabella = doc.getElementsByClass("ul").first();
    List<String> titoli = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> descrizioni = new ArrayList<>();
    // prendo gli elementi che mi interessano dalla tabella
    Elements sezioni = tabella.getElementsByClass("li");
    for(Element sezione : sezioni)//per ogni sezione tra gli elementi ricavati prima
    {
        //ricavo ogni riga nella sezione
        Elements righe_sezione = sezione.getElementsByClass("li");
        for(Element riga : righe_sezione)
        {
            //prelevo la cella delle info
            Element info = riga.getElementsByClass("li").first();

            // ricavo il titolo
            // (con .text() ottengo il testo non formattato
            String titolo = info.getElementsByClass("li").first().text();

            // ricavo la descrizione
            // (uso .first() per essere sicuro che sia proprio la descrizione
            // e non i moderatori )
            String descrizione = info.getElementsByTag("li").first().text();

            // inserisco nei rispettivi arraylist
            titoli.add(titolo);
            descrizioni.add(descrizione);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I need to parse this page: https://it.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sonno

Comment: Explain better what your problem is. Do get an Error? A StackTrace maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You try to select `<ul>` elements I guess, but what you do is look for elements with a class `ul`. Instead you should do this:

```
Element tabella = doc.getElementsByTag("ul").first();
```

or you can use a CSS selector:

```
Element tabella = doc.select("ul").first();
```

Comment: ok but this ? 
                        //prelevo la cella delle info
                        Element info = riga.getElementsByClass("ul").first();

                        // ricavo il titolo

Comment: You must change all your code to the correct methods of course!